# Differential Equation of Oxygen Sag Curve

Tags: differential

In the book I found this differential Equation and it's solution, Could anyone explain how to solve the equation.

[Here the ss of the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgWgf.jpg)
D is the oxygen Deficit and D0 is the initial oxygen deficit at t = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an inhomogeneous linear differential equation which is solved with the method of undetermined coefficients as detailed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation .